# Xcode uses Homebrewed gcc instead system default

Tags: xcode, gcc, homebrew

For some reason Xcode started using `/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9` instead of whatever it was using before. Not sure what I did to make this change, but it breaks builds because Xcode tries passing incompatible arguments to `gcc`.

What can I do to make Xcode use its default settings again?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to reset Xcode to its default settings with:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode
```

This is a bit extreme as you lose all of your other settings but works.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your xcode-select path; it should be /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/